# Exit the loop and terminate the program in C program

Tags: c

I have a program that reads a user's input and prints them out on separate lines. I am trying to create a loop and exit  the  loop,  and  terminate  the  program when 'quit' is entered.

such as if the user inputs the sentence 'quit this program the program' will read the sentence and only print quit then exit the program (not print the rest of the sentence on separate lines)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100

int main(void) {

    int c = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter a sentence.\n\n input: ");

    /* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */
    while (n < MAXC && (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            printf ("\n");
        else
            printf ("%c", c);
        n++;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    if (n == MAXC) /* read and discard remaining chars in stdin */
        while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. You can break out of a loop with the `break` statement

Comment: Need to put `c` in a buffer of length `MAXC` (or `MAXC + 1` if you want it to be a string) then search for the word `quit`.

Comment: As mentioned above, the question is missing. To leave from your loop when the word "quit" is entered, declare a buffer equal to the size of the input you're reading + 1, and stack up the characters in this buffer ensuring it is null terminated. Finally, `strcmp` your buffer with your word.

Comment: Assuming you define your quit command as a literal string `const char command[]="quit";` you can use a "progress" variable `p` to track how far the user is through entering the quit command. Initially set `p` to zero. Then, if the user presses 'q' you can increment `p` to 1, and so on. `if(command[p]==c)++p; else p=0;` Once `p` is equal to the length of the quit command (which is a constant), you can quit.

Comment: Note "words" can be separated by punctuation too, and numbers are not words; a user migt also enter a TAB character.  Consider using `!isalpha( c )` or `ispunct( c ) || isspace( c )`, rather then `c == ' '`.

Answer (score 2):

To look for a sequence in a stream, increment an index to the trigger sequence every time a character matches the current indexed character.  On a mismatch reset the counter.  If the index gets to the end of the trigger sequence, you are done:

```
int quit_index = 0 ;
const char* quit_trigger = "quit" ;

// read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line
// until the quit trigger sequence is read.
while( quit_trigger[quit_index] != 0
       n < MAXC && 
       (c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
{
    if (c == ' ')
        printf ("\n");
    else
        printf ("%c", c);
    n++;

    // While sequence matches the trigger sequence, increment index, 
    // otherwise reset to zero on mismatch.
    quit_index = (c == quit_trigger[quit_index]) ? quit_index + 1 : 0 ;
}
```